# Tensorflow slim validation accuracy is around 0 for models(mobilenet, inceptionv2) trained from scratch on imagenet

Tags: tensorflow, slim, imagenet

I trained tensorflow slim default models like mobilenetv1 and inceptionv2 on imagenet from scratch.
The loss is decreasing from ~7 to ~2, training seems to be good.
But the validation accuracy using eval_image_classifier.py shows around 0.
Checkpoints trained from scratch is used for validation accuracy check.

While I use tensorflow provided pretrained checkpoints of mobilenetv1 to check validation accuracy, Accuracy is about 70% as claimed in the site.

I also trained darknet-19 from scratch and the validation accuracy is around 60%, and I added batch normalization to vgg16 and trained on imagenet, the validation accuracy is also above 50%.

Could anyone tell me why default models on slim like mobilenetv1 and inceptionv2 trained from scratch shows around 0 accuracy on validation?

Comment: It's not 100% clear this is a programming question. Maybe you can include the commands you use in the question.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with [tag:mit-scratch]